# Ubuntu Server and QEMU - "Could not initialize SDL"

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am following the instructions on [RunningKVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/RunningKVM).

My host runs Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 (64 bit)

I downloaded the Ubuntu Server ISO file:

```
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.2/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso
```

And then I ran:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 vdisk.img 10G
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda vdisk.img -cdrom ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso -boot d  -m 384
```

Error:

```
Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting
```

From what I understand, this is because I am not running it from X windows machine.

Then, after googling, I added `-vga none` and  I ran:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -vga none -hda vdisk.img -cdrom ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso -boot d  -m 384
```

And again I got the same error.

Then I ran with `-nographic`:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic  -hda vdisk.img -cdrom ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso -boot d  -m 384
```

And this was stuck without any error (I waited over 10 minutes).
So I had to kill this process from a different machine.

What is the correct way to install when the host does not have x windows 
with this setup?

Comment: Have you tried `qemu -curses`? You may also want to try running `gksudo qemu-system-x86_64 <switches>` as well

Comment: I had just tried qemu -curses...

Comment: Poke: three weeks past by. Any ideas about the answer ?

Comment: My previous comment from 28 of November was not sent fully, so I am repeating it in full: 
I had just tried qemu -curses, and I see one line on a black screen, saying:  1024x 768 Graphic mode (in blue). And I cannot do anything from this screen,

Answer (score 0):

Try with `-vga qxl` (you must `modprobe` the `qxl` module first), or `-vga virtio`.